# nextJS/webpack: How to handle SASS files with font

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js

I'm trying to configure webpack of my nextJS application to handle some SASS files, which looks like this:

```
@font-face
  font-family: 'Marcellus'
  font-style: normal
  font-weight: 400
  src: local('Marcellus-Regular'), url('/fonts/marcellus/Marcellus-Regular.ttf') format('truetype')
```

The `@` gives me an unexpected token error. So I tried to add some custom webpack configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: function (config) {
    config.module = {
      rules: [
        { test: /(\.sass$)/, loaders: ['sass-loader'] },
        { test: /(\.css$)/, loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'] },
        { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }
      ]
    }
    return config
  }
}
```

With this the *.js files aren't recognized anymore and I'm not quite sure if the SASS files are loaded correctly. I'm very unexperienced with webpack.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add multiple loaders for the SASS file:

```
    test: /\.sass$/,
        use: [{
            loader: 'style-loader', // creates style nodes from JS strings
        }, {
            loader: 'css-loader', // translates CSS into CommonJS
        }, {
            loader: 'sass-loader', // compiles Sass to CSS
        }],
```

Source: [Sass-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/)